# ERC 20- Tokens missing

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am not a Core developer, however, I tried to write a code for someone. Everything went fine but I am unable however after that am unable to transfer or get to know where are the tokens which got created. Am I doing something wrong?

here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract ReserveToken {

    string public name = "Reserve";      //  token name
    string public symbol = "RST";           //  token symbol
    uint256 public decimals = 6;            //  token digit

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    uint256 public totalSupply = 50000000000000;
    bool public stopped = false;

    uint256 constant valueFounder = 100000000000000000;
    address owner = 0x0;

    modifier isOwner {
        assert(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    modifier isRunning {
        assert (!stopped);
        _;
    }

    modifier validAddress {
        assert(0x0 != msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function ExominiumToken(address _addressFounder) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        totalSupply = valueFounder;
        balanceOf[_addressFounder] = valueFounder;
        Transfer(0x0, _addressFounder, valueFounder);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) isRunning validAddress returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) isRunning validAddress returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
        require(allowance[_from][msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) isRunning validAddress returns (bool success) {
        require(_value == 0 || allowance[msg.sender][_spender] == 0);
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function stop() isOwner {
        stopped = true;
    }

    function start() isOwner {
        stopped = false;
    }

    function setName(string _name) isOwner {
        name = _name;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[0x0] += _value;
        Transfer(msg.sender, 0x0, _value);
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}
```

Comment: According to EIP-20 specification, `decimals` should be `uint8`, not `uint256`.

Answer (score 1):

The contract and the constructor have different names

```
contract ReserveToken {

...

    function ExominiumToken(address _addressFounder) {
```

The constructor should have the exact same name than the contract. Otherwise it will not be called when deploying the contract and the storage will be uninitialized.

Comment: and if it is same then? Do you see any other issue with the contract

Comment: @Vaibhav The answer should fix the issue where the tokens were not assigned. For another issue you should create a new question.